# How to sort javascript array of objects, based upon a key

Tags: javascript

How can I sort this array based upon id ?

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": 38938888,
    "subInternalUpdates": true,
  },
  {
    "id": 38938887,
    "subInternalUpdates": true
  },
  {
    "id": 38938889,
    "subInternalUpdates": true
  }
];
const sorted_by_name = arr.sort((a, b) => a.id > b.id);
console.log(sorted_by_name);
```

expected output

```
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 38938887,
    "subInternalUpdates": true
  },
{
    "id": 38938888,
    "subInternalUpdates": true,
  },
  {
    "id": 38938889,
    "subInternalUpdates": true
  }
];
```

Comment: your expected results matches ... though, I'd use `a.id - b.id` instead

Comment: I feel like you already did it, what is the problem?

Comment: @SeidAkhmedAgitaev OP's array is still not sorted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Much better return `a.id - b.id` when you order the array:

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": 38938888,
    "subInternalUpdates": true,
  },
  {
    "id": 38938887,
    "subInternalUpdates": true
  },
  {
    "id": 38938889,
    "subInternalUpdates": true
  }
];
const sorted_by_name = arr.sort((a, b) => {
   return a.id - b.id;
});
console.log(sorted_by_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly compare using `a-b`, otherwise, if you're comparing the values, you need to return -1, 0 or 1 for sort to work properly

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": 38938888,
    "subInternalUpdates": true,
  },
  {
    "id": 38938887,
    "subInternalUpdates": true
  },
  {
    "id": 38938889,
    "subInternalUpdates": true
  }
];
const sorted_by_name = arr.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
console.log(sorted_by_name);
```